# Relative path doesn't work on shared directory

Tags: batch-file

`xcopy "D:\CCStudio\rtos" panasonic /s /e`

The folder `panasonic` and the bat file are on the same level in the directory structure, although on another machine I have access to.

When I use the bat script on my PC everything works fine. But when I put the bat script into the remote shared folder, it doesn't work as expected. The problem seems not to be the source, instead the destination address is the key in the problem. When I replace `pansonic' whit its absolute address, the script works.

So why should I specify absolute path for destination? Recall that the destination is external path. It is shared folder on another windows machine.

Comment: When using relative paths they relate to the *current working directory*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I currently run a bat from a shared drive to copy to another shared drive. This is what I use to get it working fine. Adjust as needed.

```
cd /d %~dp0
xcopy /s "D:\CCStudio\rtos" "panasonic\" /E
```

`cd /d %~dp0` will change the directory to what ever the batch file is in allowing you to use relative paths. This script will copy the files in `rtos` to `panasonic`. Folder path will look something like this `X:\Shared\Network\panasonic\RtosFiles.ini` assuming `RtosFiles.ini` was in `D:\CCStudio\rtos` and the batch was run in `X:\Shared\Network\`